# Else statement is running twice jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, append

https://jsfiddle.net/mpcbLgtt/2/

What I am making: A function that when a div of class card is clicked it should add its name to an array called deck and add its id to an array called cardIds.

Here is the card:

```
<div class='card' id='1' name='dinosaur'>Dinosaur</div>
<div class='card' id='2' name='crab'>Crab</div>
```

If there is already 2 of this card in the array, then it should do nothing.

If there is none of the card then it appends a deckItem div onto the decklist div.

```
<div class="decklist"></div>
```

Here is the problem. If there is already 1 of the card in the array, instead of appending the card to the 'decklist' div, I want to remove the previous card and add a new card which has "x2" on it.

The code at the moment is able to remove the previous card. However, when it appends the following code it does it twice. For example. I click on a card called "Dinosaur" it will append it to the array. Then if I click on the card "Dinosaur" again then it will output "Dinosaur x2" "Dinosaur x2" instead of just "Dinosaur x2"

```
$(".decklist").append($replacement);
```

The full code for this is below.

```
var deck = [];
var cardIds = [];
$(".card").click(function(){
    $cardName = $(this).attr("name");
        $cardId = $(this).attr("id");
        $occurances = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i<deck.length; i++) {
            if (deck[i]==$cardName) {
                $occurances++;
            }
        }

        //if there are less than 2 of this card in deck array
        if ($occurances<2) {
            //add the card to array
            deck.push($cardName);
            cardIds.push($cardId);
            deck.sort();
            //empty the decklist div
            $(".decklist").empty(); 
            //go through all the cards in the deck array.
            //if that card appears once append it else replace it
            for (var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
                //count the number of times this card is in the deck array
                $count = 0;
                for (var k = 0; k < deck.length; k++) {
                    if (deck[k] == deck[i]) {
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
                if ($count == 1) {
                    //this runs once
                    var $toBeAppended = $("<div class='deckItem' id='"+cardIds[i]+"'>"+deck[i]+"</div>");
                    $(".decklist").append($toBeAppended);
                } else {
                    //this runs twice
                    var $replacement = $("<div class='deckItem' id='"+cardIds[i]+"'>"+deck[i]+" x2</div>");
                    $(".decklist").remove(".deckItem#"+cardIds[i]);
                    $(".decklist").append($replacement);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you binding click multiple times?

Comment: it is inside a loop so the `if` will be evaluated each iteration. Create basic demo that replicates issue. Hard for us to mentally evaluate your app with various scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have multiple problems.

- Your count for each card does not exclude the duplicates already matched
- You have duplicate ID values in the page which is invalid HTML and only the first match will be found by a browser. I added a `card` prefix to the lower cards ids and uniquely numbered the top cards `1-3`.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var deck = [];
  var cardIds = [];
  $(".card").click(function() {
    $cardName = $(this).attr("name");
    $cardId = $(this).attr("id");
    $occurances = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
      if (deck[i] == $cardName) {
        $occurances++;
      }
    }
      //if there are less than 2 of this card in deck array
    if ($occurances < 2) {
      //add the card to array
      deck.push($cardName);
      cardIds.push($cardId);
      deck.sort();
      console.log(deck);
      //empty the decklist div
      $(".decklist").empty();
      //go through all the cards in the deck array.
      //if that card appears once append it else replace it
      alert(deck.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
        //count the number of times this card is in the deck array
        $count = 1;
        for (var k = i + 1; k < deck.length; k++) {
          if (deck[k] == deck[i]) {
            $count++;
            i++; // Skip the item just matched as well
          }
        }
        alert($count);
        if ($count == 1) {
          //this runs once
          var $toBeAppended = $("<div class='deckItem' id='card" + cardIds[i] + "'>" + deck[i] + "</div>");
          $(".decklist").append($toBeAppended);
        } else if ($count == 2) {
          //this runs twice
          var $replacement = $("<div class='deckItem' id='" + cardIds[i] + "'>" + deck[i] + " x2</div>");
          $(".decklist").remove(".deckItem#" + cardIds[i]);
          $(".decklist").append($replacement);
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/mpcbLgtt/3/

Comment: I think this is on the right lines. But instead of adding a card after one click and adding card x2 after second, this adds nothing after first click and adds card after second click

Comment: @TomOborne: Any chance you can put your question into a JSFiddle etc? I don't have the spare time right now to setup a demo and debug :)

Comment: Good idea, I'll make a Jfiddle and reply soon

Comment: @TomOborne: No problem. Please accept as answer when you can :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the counting.
If deck=[Max, Dinosaur, Dinosaur] you count 1 Max, and then *for each* Dinosaur you count 2 Dinosaurs.

**Edit, this is wrong**: Your counting should start from k=i+1, and not from 0 - this way you wont count past occurrences.

Your counting should conciser past occurrences, you can make an array and after the first occurrence put the card there, and before counting check if the card was added to the array.

Comment: Sorry, max was a typo - should have said dinosaur too

Comment: Okay, even with deck=[Dinosaur, Dinosaur] my answer stays the same - you'll count 2 Dinosaurs for each Dinosaur (for i=0 count will be 2 and also for i=1 count will be 2).

Comment: Good early pickup, but that was only one of the problems here.